# Why am I getting the "cannot find image" error in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function

```
function openImage(id){

        var full = "full"+id;
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "full"+id;

        window.open(img);
    }
```

When I do `window.open(full)`, it works perfectly fine, but when I do `window.open(img)`, I get the error

> "cannot find ../desktop/website/object%20HTML..."

The image is for sure placed in the “website" folder too

Is there any reason why I'm getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: The browser is telling you it can't find the image. No point arguing about it.

Comment: [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) expects an URL, not an Image object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take an DOM representation of an HTML img element and convert it to a string, the result is not a URL.

The first argument of `window.open` needs to be a URL.

You could extract the URL from the `src` property:

```
window.open(img.src);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `img` is an object, not a string. `window.open` expects the first arguments to be a string and casts passed parameter to string type. It means that image will call its `toString()` method in order to get string, which is `[object HTMLImageElement]`. And this is what you get: strange url which fails to load anything:

```
../desktop/website/object/%20object HTMLImageElement%5D
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.open` needs a String, but you passed in an Object, so what happened is

```
window.open("[object HTMLImageElement]");
```